# Dealing with large numbers with GMP-style performance in Go

Tags: performance, go, benchmarking, arbitrary-precision

I'm learning Go and I started using the `math/big` package to deal with arbitrary-length integer.

I wrote this program that computes the n-th Fibonacci number : (removed the `import`s) :

```
func main() {
    imax, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    var a, b, c big.Int
    a.SetUint64(0)
    b.SetUint64(1)
    for i := 0; i < imax; i++ {
        c.Set(&b)
        b.Add(&b, &a)
        a.Set(&c)
    }
    fmt.Println(a.String())
}
```

Here's the code for the C program :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int imax = atoi(argv[1]);

    mpz_t a, b, c;
    mpz_inits(a, b, c, NULL);
    mpz_set_ui(a, 0);
    mpz_set_ui(b, 1);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
        mpz_swap(a, b);
        mpz_add(b, a, b);
    }

    char* astr = NULL;
    astr = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, a);
    printf("%s\n", astr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Go program computes the term 100,000 in 0.1 second (average), while the C equivalent, using the GMP lib, runs in 0.04 second only. That's two times slower.

Is there a way to get the same performance in my Go program ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for a code review.

Comment: How is it a request for code review ? I do not want to optimize *this* program specifically, but to learn a way to get the same perfs in the two languages. I tried to make the two programs as similar as possible to get a non biased benchmark. An answer could be another arbitrary-precision arithmetic Go library for example.

Comment: If you want to compare operations, you need to setup a reproducible benchmark. We don't know how you are compiling and running your code. On my system the go code computes 10000 in ~55ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print to stdout, it's slow. What result do you get for this code?

```
package main

import (
    "math/big"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    max, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    a, b := big.NewInt(0), big.NewInt(1)
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        a.Add(a, b)
        a, b = b, a
    }
}
```

Go is not hand crafted assembler code.

Your value of 100,000 is too small for a reliable benchmark. Use 1,000,000 or another value that runs for at least ten seconds.

Comment: I tried with imax = 1,000,000, redirecting output to /dev/null, and it took 9 seconds for Go, 3.6 seconds for C. The advantage is pretty clear. I will try your code later.

Comment: OK, the results with your code are interesting. It computes the 1,000,000th term in 4.5 seconds, while the C code (without printing) takes 3.5 seconds. I guess the performance depends on the library and will be similar if I use the Go GMP binding. Thanks !

Comment: Redirecting output to `/dev/null` does not help: the program still has to do a syscall each time something gets output. Please consider using benchmarking facilities of the standard package `testing`. And don't print anything in your code being benchmarked -- at least when you are not going to specifically benchmark I/O

Answer (score 1):

In general, GMP is faster because it's crafted for performance. Under the hood, you may find that it is partly written in assembly, which reduces functions' call overhead, may utilize some CPU instructions like `ADX` and so on.

If you care about performance, then you could use [`mpz_fib_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions.html#Number-Theoretic-Functions) routine, that would be even faster, as it gains from some math trickery.

The direct answer to your question is probably to use some Go's binding for GMP.